# Remove Duplicates from the List recursively

Tags: scala, recursion, pattern-matching

I want to remove duplicates from the list recursively using pattern matching with Scala

here is my input

```
val xs = List(1,2,3,4,6,3,2,7,9,4)
```

Tried code:

```
  def removeDuplicates(xs : List[Int]) : List[Int] = xs match {
  case Nil =>Nil
  case x::ys => { 
      if(ys.contains(x)){
      removeDuplicates(ys)
    } else {
        }
/// ???
  }
}
```

I was stuck at the question mark, how to appened my result to the mutable list and return it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You need to keep track of the current state: already seen elements using a set (for fast lookup), and the new list being constructed:

```
@tailrec
def removeDuplicatesRec(
  remaining: List[Int], 
  seen: Set[Int], 
  acc: List[Int]
): List[Int] = remaining match {
  case Nil => acc
  case head :: tail => 
    if (!seen.contains(head)) removeDuplicatesRec(tail, seen + head, acc :+ head)
    else removeDuplicatesRec(tail, seen, acc)
}

def removeDuplicates(xs: List[Int]): List[Int] =
  removeDuplicatesRec(xs, Set.empty, List.empty)
```

Comment: I was trying this in data bricks community notebook, there are some errors.

This is too complicated is there anyway to optimize more

Comment: @Krish: You just need to `import annotation._` and replace the two calls to removeDuplicates in removeDuplicatesRec with removeDuplicatesRec, then it works as intended, too.

Answer (score 3):

You're close:

```
 def removeDuplicates(xs : List[Int]) : List[Int] = xs match {
  case Nil => Nil
  case x::ys => if (ys.contains (x)) removeDuplicates (ys) else
      x :: removeDuplicates (ys)
 }

scala> removeDuplicates (List (1,2,3,4,6,3,2,7,9,4))
res143: List[Int] = List(1, 6, 3, 2, 7, 9, 4)
```

While this is a brief solution, it isn't tail recursive and therefore vulnerable for stackoverflows - whereas Jean Logearts solution solves the problem.

Here is an alternative solution with an inner function, tailrecursive too:

```
def removeDuplicates (xsOuter : List[Int]) : List[Int] = {

  @annotation.tailrec
  def removeDuplicates (xs: List[Int], collected: List[Int]) : List[Int] = xs match {
    case Nil => collected
    case x :: ys => if (collected.contains (x)) removeDuplicates (ys, collected) else
      removeDuplicates (ys, x :: collected)
  }

  removeDuplicates (xsOuter, Nil)
}

scala> removeDuplicates (List (1,2,3,4,6,3,2,7,9,4))
res151: List[Int] = List(9, 7, 6, 4, 3, 2, 1)
```

with a bias to the first elements, but with the result reversed, which can be easily corrected by returning `collected.reverse` in the Nil case, if it is important.

The outer function serves the job to provide a simple, one-argument interface to the user, so he doesn't need to provide an empty List.

Note, that the solution is crying for a type annotation, since it doesn't depend at all on the List elements being of type Int:

```
scala> def removeDuplicates [A] (xsOuter : List[A]) : List[A] = {
     | 
     |   @annotation.tailrec
     |   def removeDuplicates (xs: List[A], collected: List[A]) : List[A] = xs match {
     |     case Nil => collected
     |     case x :: ys => if (collected.contains (x)) removeDuplicates (ys, collected) else
     |       removeDuplicates (ys, x :: collected)
     |   }
     | 
     |   removeDuplicates (xsOuter, Nil)
     | }
removeDuplicates: [A](xsOuter: List[A])List[A]

scala> removeDuplicates (List (1,2,3,4,6,3,2,7,9,4))
res152: List[Int] = List(9, 7, 6, 4, 3, 2, 1)
```

Comment: is it the same way,to remove consecutive duplicates

if (ys.head!==Nil && x==ys.head)
  removeConsecutiveDups(ys)
  else
  x::removeConsecutiveDups(ys)

Comment: List(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,4,4,4,4,5,6,7,7,7) for the above comment @user-unknown

Comment: @Krish: It's easy, to put the code into an editor, copy it, modify it a bit and then paste it into the REPL. If you enter ": pas"(te) into the editor, you can paste a block of code as a whole into the REPL (which is only sometimes important, but often visually more appealing) and - if it is accepted (hit Ctrl-D for signalling end-of-file for the pasting) test, if it works as expeceted.

Comment: To the content: ys.head!==Nil is probably a typo, meaning ys.head != Nil, but that's a type error, since the head of a List in never Nil, but if you correct that to `if (ys != Nil && ..)`, it works as wanted.

Comment: I am getting stack overflow error for consecutive duplicates. case x::ys => if(ys!=Nil||x==ys.head)
  removeConsecutiveDups(ys)
  else
  x::removeConsecutiveDups(ys)

Comment: Well a) It has to be (ys != Nil && x == ys.head) - hasn't it? b) And to avoid stack overflows orient at the @tailcall solutions. I guess you had much longer input than shown in the comment #3? The annotation only forces the compiler to check, whether tail call optimization is possible and gives you feedback. If it is possible, even without annotation, the code is optimized in binary form to loop style, avoiding stack overflows. But without annotation, you don't get a warning, if tail call optimization wasn't possible.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a classic approach using an inner function and tail recursion. The tail recursion may not be necessary for small lists but it is easier for me to reason about.

```
  def removeDuplicates(xs : List[Int]) : List[Int] =  {
    @scala.annotation.tailrec
    def accumulator(xs: List[Int], acc: List[Int]):List[Int] = xs match {
      case Nil => acc
      case h::t if(!acc.contains(h)) => accumulator(t, h :: acc)
      case h::t if(acc.contains(h)) =>  accumulator(t, acc)
    }
    accumulator(xs, List[Int]())
  }

scala> removeDuplicates(List(1,2,3,4,6,3,2,7,9,4))
res16: List[Int] = List(9, 7, 6, 4, 3, 2, 1)
```

Of course, `distinct` is the preferred way to do this but this is a good exercise. `distinct` can be used to verify your solution though.

```
scala> List(1,2,3,4,6,3,2,7,9,4).distinct == removeDuplicates(List(1,2,3,4,6,3,2,7,9,4)).sorted
res21: Boolean = true
```